# Mail sending issue using dreamhost with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to send mail using using dreamhost credential with ruby on rails.

My development.rb file mail setting as following.

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "dreamhost.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "www.dreamhost.com",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV['mailer'],
  password: ENV['mailer_password']
}
```

Mail is not able to send using above mail configuration I'm getting error like Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused for "dreamhost.com" port 587).

Can any one help me for this issue?

Comment: What is the issue?  You need to provide more details for anyone to help you.

Comment: I'm not getting exact issue. I've added mail credential and domain setting on config/development.rb file. I'm not sure for what I have to add into address and domain when I send mail using dreamhost credential.

Answer (score 0):

This is my profile I use on Dreamhost

```
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'notifications@mywebsite.org'}
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'sub5.mail.dreamhost.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'mywebsite.org',
  user_name:            'notifications@mywebsite.org',
  password:             'mypassword',
  authentication:       :login,
  enable_starttls_auto: false  }
```

Note that `sub5.mail.dreamhost.com` is domain-dependent address of your [datacenter server](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214918038#Server_names).

NB: Password should be hidden into [ENV variables or other external file outside version control](http://rubyrobot.github.io/blog/2014/04/08/secure-rails-deployment-and-passwords-best-practices/)